# Building memory blocks in LyX

Tags: lyx

I was wondering if it's possible to somehow create similar structures in LyX:

[image]

The colors does not mean to me, but to know how to create the cool structures will be great.

Tried to find similar threads but without any success. Also tried to read the `tikz` documentation to see if its possible to achieve it.

Comment: And what has your reading of the TikZ documentation shown? Actually that's quite a basic task…

Comment: You don't need a hammersledge like TikZ for that.A simple `tabular` with `colortbl` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Very short approximation:

[image: memory]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\xoutofeight[2][black]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\xstep{.6cm}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\ystep{\baselineskip}
        \fill[#1!40] (0,0) rectangle ({#2*\xstep},\ystep);
        \draw[#1,xstep=\xstep,ystep=\ystep] (0,0) grid ({8*\xstep},\ystep);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    short num: \xoutofeight{2}

    char* str: \xoutofeight{8}

    short num: \xoutofeight[green!80!black]{2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple tabulars with `xcolor` and `array` can do that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{p{0.5cm}|}}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{WhiteSmoke!60!Lavender}& & & & & & &\rule{0pt}{1.5cm} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\vskip 1cm

\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{>{\columncolor{WhiteSmoke!60!Lavender}}p{0.5cm}|}*{6}{p{0.5cm}|}}
  \hline
  & & & & & & &\rule{0pt}{1.5cm} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular} \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]